# strong deformation retracts & neighbourhood deformation retracts

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, retraction

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$ be a closed subspace.
Assume that $A$ is a strong deformation retract of $X$.

Is it true that for every open subspace $U \subset X$, $A \subset U$, there exists an open $V \subset U$, $A \subset V$ such that $A$ is a strong deformation retract of $V$?

What if we assume $X$ is a metric space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [comb space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space) is a counter-example (and is a metric space).

Observe that the comb space strongly deformation retracts onto the point $(0,1)$.  First deformation retract the "spokes" $\{\frac{1}{n}\} \times [0,1]$ onto $\{\frac{1}{n}\} \times \{0\}$, then deformation retract $[0,1] \times \{0\}$ onto the origin, then deformation retract $\{0\} \times [0,1]$ onto the point $(0,1)$.

However, consider the intersection $U$ of the comb space with $[0,1] \times (\frac{1}{2}, 1]$.  $U$ is open in the comb space, and any neighborhood of $(0,1)$ in $U$ intersects infinitely many of the spokes and hence is disconnected.  A disconnected set cannot deformation retract onto a point, so we're done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Will it be possible to construct an example with locally contractible $X$?

Comment: @gsmirnov I was wondering the same thing, but I'm not sure.  Your question reminds me a little bit of the theory of absolute neighborhood retract spaces, and I'm worried that one of the crazy counter-examples in that theory will also cause problems here.